# Python webserver for mobile app

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, python, gunicorn

I would like to setup a python webserver for my mobile app

It will not serve any media, css, html, etc..
Therefore I thought about gunicorn + python app without nginx, at least for the beginning

The reason I'm asking is that on gunicorn site they suggest to use it behind nginx, but I assume it's for static files serving and requests buffering

Am I right about this...?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Nginx will also give you better control of DNS routing and SSL termination so your web app won't have to. But mostly its job is to handle tons of requests at once and buffer for slow clients.

For development purposes or if you don't expect lots of connections, you probably don't need Nginx.